# If there exists probability measure that maximizes expectation to a function, does this function always have a maximum?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

I want to know if $\mathrm{max}_p \mathbb E_{p(x)} f(x)$ exists, does $\mathrm{max}_x f(x)$ always exist?

If not, what conditions (as minor as possible) do I need to put on $f$ for this statement to be true?

My attempt:

In the case of discrete $p$, if $p^*$ maximizes $\mathrm{max}_p \mathbb E_p(x) f(x)$ and $f$ is not constant on the support of $p^*$, then there exists $a$, $b$ s.t. $f(b) > f(a)$ and $p(a)\cdot p(b) > 0$. Then $p^{**}$ with $p^{**}(b) = p^*(a)+p^*(b)$ and $p^{**}(a) = 0$ ($p^{**} = p^*$ elsewhere) has $\mathbb E_{p^{**}}(x) f(x) > \mathbb E_{p^*}(x) f(x)$, contradiction. Therefore $f$ is constant on the support of $p^*$, then we must have $f(c) = \mathrm{max}_x f(x)$ for any $c$ in the support of $p^*$. I have no idea for the case of a general $p$.

Comment: Suppose $x\in[0,1)$ and $p$ consists of only the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x$. Then $\max_p E_p f(x) = .5$ but $\max_{x\in [0,1)} x$ does not exist. It seems difficult to make existence conclusions about the max from the expectation because $\max_\theta E f_\theta \leq E \max_\theta f_\theta$. However, if your class of $p$ is large enough to include all singletons across the entire range of $x$ and these maxima are guaranteed to be attained, then your conclusion holds by construction.